# What is it called when you mess up or fumble on simple task in front of someone you are attracted to?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, north-american-english

For example, most adults can drive well enough it's an unconscious know how to the do's and do nots of the laws of the road. Yet when they have their crush as the passenger they almost crash because their attention subconsciously was more focused on them then the road.

Comment: That's known as the crush-or-crash dilemma. Tell the crush to find another ride or risk death.

Comment: You are [**distracted**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distracted) :) and [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distracted) says *harassed, confused, or disturbed especially by strong feelings*.

Comment: While not crush-specific, your example could be described as [choking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/choke).

Comment: In nearly 70 years of listening, reading and watching I've never met any such phrase, term or word.

If this is about focussing on the road, read Weather Vane, above. Everyone fit to hold a licence not only knows, but always follows the rules of the road. 

Who are 'they' whose crush as passenger means they almost crash because their attention was more focused on the crush than the road?

Is that you? People you know? People you've heard about in a survey? Who else?